# Thunderbird remote profile is huge

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, roaming-profiles

A long time ago (with Thunderbird 2 or 3) I knew a solution how to permanently delete old messages which are stored in the folder `appdata/roaming/profile/xxxxx/mail`
Unfortunately I can't remember how I did it, and also can't find a solution on the net( My messages size in Thunderbird is approx. 700 MB, in the remote folder almost 10 GB. How can I clear out the already deleted (in Thunderbird ) messages? I'm using Thunderbird 17 now.

Answer (score 0):

If the messages have already been deleted, have you tried [compacting the folders](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Compacting_folders)?

As the page states:

> ... switch to working offline using **File -> Offline -> Work Offline**, select an account and then manually compact the folders in that account using **File -> Compact Folders** instead. You can also compact a specific folder by right clicking on it and selecting "Compact" from the context menu:

[image: 1]

> You have several additional options if you are using a IMAP account. If you check **Tools -> Account Settings -> Server Settings -> Clean up ("Expunge") Inbox on Exit** it will compact the Inbox folder when you exit Thunderbird. If you check "Empty Trash on Exit" it will also empty and compact the Trash folder when you exit.